# Save split by punctuation

Tags: java, regex

I need to safely split Java string into words and punctuation.

I have tried this code, but have the problem, that it doesn't separate brackets correctly.

```
String sentenceString = "Hello from the outside(outside).";
sentenceString.split("(?=,|\\.|!|\\?|\\(|\\))|\\s");
```

Actual results are

```
["Hello", "from", "the", "outside", "", "(outside", ")", "."]
```

Expected result shoud be

```
["Hello", "from", "the", "outside", "(", "outside", ")", "."]
```

Comment: Have you tried https://regex101.com/ ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of split, you should try matching the regex to get your desired output. Try using this regex in Java,

```
[a-zA-Z]+|\\p{Punct}
```

Here `[a-zA-Z]+` part matches one or more alphabets and `\\p{Punct}` part matches any punctuation character, and if you're familiar with `POSIX` representation then it is equivalent to `[[:punct:]]`. People trying to apply similar solution to languages/tools supporting `POSIX` representation can use `[a-zA-Z]+|[[:punct:]]` regex.

Java code,

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String s = "Hello from the outside(outside).";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+|\\p{Punct}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    list.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Prints the output like you wanted,

```
[Hello, from, the, outside, (, outside, ), .]
```

**Edit:** Thanks to [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) for his nice suggestion. If you want to include letters not just only from English but other languages as well, then better to use this regex,

```
\\p{L}+|\\p{P}
```

As, `\\p{L}` will not only cover English but any other language's alphabets represented in Unicode.

But, notice, this may come at a little increased cost in performance, because now, it may be trying to match not just `[a-z]` but other Unicode characters too. So there is a little trade off, so use the one that suits your needs better.

Thanks again Andreas for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: You should use `"\\p{L}+|\\p{P}"` for full Unicode support, where `\p{L}` is [Unicode Category](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode12.0.0/ch04.pdf) "Letter", and `\p{P}` is Unicode Category "Punctuation". Or, to include all displayable characters: `"[\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{N}]+|[\\p{P}\\p{S}]"` (one of more Letters, Marks, and Numbers, *or* one Punctuation or Symbol, not matching characters from the Separator and Other categories).

Comment: @Andreas: I love your suggestion, although my usage of `\p{Punct}` was more of being able to represent a punctuation character easily :) and didn't intend to cover non-English letters. But yes, in case one wants to support letters beyond English, then using `\\p{L}+|\\p{P}` would be better. Let me add this to my answer and thanks for suggesting this, I really appreciate.